# Cross-Contract execution in Ink contracts

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cross-contract-call

```
    #[ink(message)]
    pub fn test_cross_contract_call(
        &mut self,
        calls_count: u64,
    ) {
        let selector: Selector = Selector::new([0x6b, 0x25, 0xcb, 0x19]);
        let response: Result<u64> = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
                .call_type(
                    Call::new()
                        .callee(self.env().account_id())
                        .transferred_value(0)
                        .gas_limit(50000),
                )
                .call_flags(ink::env::CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(true))
                .exec_input(
                    ExecutionInput::new(selector)
                        .push_arg(calls_count)
                )
                .returns::<u64>()
                .fire();
        self.value = response.unwrap();
    }

    #[ink(message, selector = 0x6b25cb19)]
    pub fn dummy_function(
        &mut self,
        value: u64,
    ) -> u64 {
        return 45 * value;
    }
```

This is my contract code snippet. I am trying to test cross-contract call with simplest computation. But I am getting `Contracts.ContractTrapped` error. I also updated the `dummy_fuction` selector to "_" to check if i was passing wrong selector. But then also I am getting the same error.
DO we have some examples on how to call cross contract calls to self or other contract?
And Can someone explain what wrong i am doing in my code?

Comment: Did you go through [this offical documentation of Cross-Contract Calling] (https://use.ink/4.0.0-alpha.1/basics/cross-contract-calling) ? However you can also [view this code](https://github.com/123oli/ink-cross-contract-calling)

Comment: What if I am calling the self Contract (re-entrancy), Do i need to import self contract or what? What if i only have the selector information and the arguments that function is taking?

Comment: No you don't have to import, you can simply call by its name, along with necessary arguments.

Comment: But My requirement is I need to update my contract states even if my sub-contract call failed or reverted. That is why i was using cross-contract invocation for own contract function itself. The way we perform `.call()` low level contract execution in solidity.

Comment: the contract state isn't changed if calling failed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cross contract calling, what you are doing here is `Reentrancy guard` which is the process to prevent specific type of attack (i.e reentrancy attack where attacker can repeatedly call function without expected condition met) whereas `cross contract calling` is the process of interacting with other smart contract.

In order to do cross contract call you can [view this offical doc tutorial](https://use.ink/4.0.0-alpha.1/basics/cross-contract-calling) and [this repo](https://github.com/123oli/ink-cross-contract-calling). There is [delegator example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/delegator) code which is advance concept for corss contract calling.